# Regex -- ignoring the line up to a given point

Tags: regex, key-value

I have a regular expression that works on part of my data. (Perl compatible)
Given the log entry:

```
pam_vas: Authentication <succeeded> for <active directory> user: <bobtheperson> account: <bobtheperson@com.com> reason: <N/A> Access cont(upn): <bob>
```

i can use the regular expression: `[\>\:]*\s+(.*?)\:?\s\<(.+?)\>` and get the result I am looking for. (http://regexr.com/3fatg)

```
Authentication = succeeded
for = active directory
user = bobtheperson
account = bobtheperson@com.com
reason = N/A
Access cont(upn) = bob
```

Unfortunately, when I was building this regular expression, I was ignoring a vital part of the log -- the first part. 
The log actually looks like this:

```
Feb 16 20:04:37 hostname su[1111]: [id 123456 auth.info] pam_vas: Authentication <succeeded> for <active directory> user: <bobtheperson> account: <bobtheperson@com.com> reason: <N/A> Access cont(upn): <bob>
```

My extraction no longer works right -- it is thrown off by the first part. (http://regexr.com/3fbod)
How would I exclude the beginning information from this log file?

```
**Feb 16 20:04:37 hostname su[1111]: [id 123456 auth.info]** pam_vas: Authentication <succeeded> for <active directory> user: <bobtheperson> account: <bobtheperson@com.com> reason: <N/A> Access cont(upn): <bob>
```

I think I need to start my search after the last occurrence of a ]:  (right before pam_vas) but I cant figure out how to exclude that.

Comment: `[\>\:]` is better written as `[>:]`. And `[>:]*` has no effect there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Misread the question, the optimum [regex](https://regex101.com/r/RDWDgw/3) for this seems to be

`(?:^.*?pam_vas:)?\s+([^<:]*):?[ ]<([^>]*)>`

---

I played with a couple variants, but found this to be the fastest, capturing and ignoring the date-stamp

[This may suffice](https://regex101.com/r/RDWDgw/1)    `(?:^\*\*[^*]*\*\*[ ]pam_vas:)?\s+([^<:]*):?[ ]<([^>]*)>`

Unless you're using something with ignorewhitespace, you can get rid of the square brackets around single spaces. `[ ]` to .

There are shorter variants, but the drawback of capturing too much, or taking many steps to do it, on the order of 500-800, for everything I've found, vs 104 here.

```
(?:              # Opens non-capturing group (ncg)
  ^              # ^ start of line, you may actually not want this
  \*\*           # Literally ** 
  [^*]*          # Anything but *, as many times as possible 
  \*\*           # Literally **
  [ ]            # A single space, only in brackets for visibility 
  pam_vas:       # Literally pam_vas: 
)                # Closes NCG
?                # Iterates NCG 0 or 1 times, thus "optional" 
\s+              # Any number of space characters, one or more
(                # Opens Capturing Group 1
  [^<:]*         # Any Character but < or :, as many times as possible 
)                # Closes CG1 
:?               # :, 0 or 1 times 
[ ]              # A single in space, only in brackets for visibility
<                # Literally <
(                # Opens CG2 
  [^>]*          # Any character but >, as many times as possible 
)                # Closes CG2
>                # Literally >
```

Comment: Could even be written as [**`(?:.+?pam_vas:)?\s+`**](https://regex101.com/r/RDWDgw/2)

Comment: Man i wish regex101 would load here at work....seems to be a cool resource. 
In my example, i "bolded" the text i wanted to exclude. Unfortunately, it seems to have only put dual "*" in place of bold. Odd.
Anyways -- this extracts exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @izzmit Ah, I missed that -- The reason it did that is because it was part of a code box.

Comment: @izzmit Are the dates at the beginning of a line/file?

Comment: Yes. They are syslog, so each line represents a new log entry. I will be using this in splunk to parse out log data on some solaris BSM authentication logs.

Comment: @izzmit `(?:^.+?pam_vas:)?\s+([^<:]*):?[ ]<([^>]*)>` should suffice then. Captures approprately, and maintains speed.

Comment: @Jan I misread the question. Not just `could even be written as`, it the end, it turns out to be the necessary method for the quickest accurate result. I didn't realize TC added asterisks for emphasis.

Comment: @cfqueryparam: No worries, your expression is good nevertheless (+1).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it with:

```
\b                 # a word boundary
(?P<key>[\w(): ]+) # the key part - word characters, (, ), :, spaces
\h+                # at least one whitespace (can be more)
<(?P<value>[^>]+)> # the value part in <> brackets
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wEhvTH/1). This way, nothing needs to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

After a conversation with someone on the Splunk forums, i have this regex:

```
\s+([^\:\<\>]+)(?:\:?\s\<)([^\>]+)\>
```

http://regexr.com/3fbpb